# Sending a custom jQuery validation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I've been working on some custom validation (very basic). It does what I need it to do but I can't work out how to submit the form. I thought return true would work but it sadly doesn't. Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.required').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            return false;
            $(this).val("Please enter a value.");
            $(this).css("background", "#d42c43");
            $(this).css("border-color", "#d42c43");
            $(this).css("color", "#ffffff", "!important");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

All of the input fields I would like to be required have the required class in them.

Comment: `return false` stops your validation immediatly and nothing will be executed after that. You should also consider learning back-end validation which is much safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5yncmtc/2

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $('.required').each(function() {
       var form = $(e.currentTarget);
           valueToEvaul = $('#valueToEval').val();
        if (valueToEvaul == '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).val("Please enter a value.");
            $(this).css("background", "#d42c43");
            $(this).css("border-color", "#d42c43");
            $(this).css("color", "#ffffff", "!important");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikey but it still just submits the form even if empty.

Comment: @JamesGeorgeDunn Should work with preventing the default action. Edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an id to your form, and then use the `$('#form_id').submit();` method in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Since it isn't a submit, it won't submit when clicked.

The button is inside the form, right? You can navigate to it's parent recursively, until you find the form tag, and then, submit.

```
$(this).parent().submit();
```

Or you can replace your button to a submit, and it's behavior of submitting or not will be defined by the return of the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.required').each(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(e.currentTarget); //the form
           valueToEvaul = form.find('#valueToEval').val(); //the value to evaul
        if (valueToEvaul  == '') {
            $(this).val("Please enter a value.");
            $(this).css("background", "#d42c43");
            $(this).css("border-color", "#d42c43");
            $(this).css("color", "#ffffff", "!important");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Just remove the `return false`

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan but it still just submits the form even if empty.